# What is wrong when trying to enable a combobox using radiobuttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, radio-button

I'm trying to use radiobuttons to enable a combobox, though there is an error within an if statement that is saying that I am not able to add `.Checked` or `.IsChecked`. As far as I am aware there is no namespace required that isn't already added to the classes by default.

I have tried copying online tutorials exactly yet the same error still occurs or even more errors occur.

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="354,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rdoEnable" Content="Enable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="293,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rdoDisable" Content="Disable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace RadioButtonTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] array = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };

            foreach (string number in array)
            {
                comboBox.Items.Add(number);
            }

            rdoEnable.Checked = true;
        }

        private void RdoEnable_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rdoDisable.Checked)
            {
                comboBox.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                comboBox.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've posted a couple of examples of things that I have tried to imgur if it is any help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRL3n.jpg

Comment: Use `IsChecked` and `IsEbnabled` instead of `Checked` and `Enabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioButton.Checked` is an event, you can not assign bool value to it, only attach event handler (method, which will be invoked when event is raised)

`RadioButton.IsChecked` is a property which gives current state. It has `Nullable<bool>` type, so condition should be in form

```
if (rdoDisable.IsChecked == true) {} else {}
```

or simple:

```
comboBox.IsEnabled = (rdoDisable.IsChecked == true);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested which fixed the errors and the program is able to run, but the program is not disabling the combobox when I select the disable radiobutton. Are you able to check if I have completed what you have suggested is right, I've posted an image of the code and the program running on imgur. https://imgur.com/a/uzYBDMa

Comment: @Steve, `RdoEnable_Checked` method is not connected to event. make it  `<RadioButton x:Name="rdoDisable" Content="Disable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RdoEnable_Checked" Unchecked="RdoEnable_Checked"/>`